# Как показывать контент только для неавторизованных пользователей, использую Spring Security и JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

Разбираюсь со Spring Security, JSP и taglib. Хочу отображать один блок текста для авторизованных пользователей и другой в том же месте только для неавторизованных. С теми кто залогинен все понятно:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
   Content
</sec:authorize>
```

А как определить пользователей без роли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
 Content
</sec:authorize>
```